# G++ cannot find library unless it is full path

Tags: c++, linker

After installing boost from EPEL 5 on 64-bit CentOS 5.8 I run insto strange problem. I cannot link in other way then providing full path. I.e this works:

```
g++ ... /usr/lib64/libboost_python.so.5
```

But this cannot find `-lboost_python`

```
g++ ... -L/usr/lib64/ -lboost_python
```

What could be wrong?

PS. LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not help. It do finds some libraries but even symlinking into /usr/lib does not help. I am building 64-version of program (checked by `file *.o`).

Comment: Library name should be `libboost_python.so` and not `libboost_python.so.5` for g++ to find it. Isn't there a soft link `libboost_python.so` to `libboost_python.so.5`?

Comment: older boost libraries came with version specific link lines which required numbers in the library path, but a standard boost install should include the relevant soft link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a symlink : `ln -s /usr/lib64/liboost_python.so /usr/lib64/libboost_python.so.5`, then try again.